# Where is the treasure John is looking for?

Tags: riddle

Not much was at stake on John's last visit to the oracle. But his grandfather had told him, in his dying moments, the location of a unimaginable treasure. Forgetful as usual, John messed up again. Although not fully prepared, he visits the oracle once more, only to take heat from the oracle in the form of these riddles:

> When you are out prowling for friendly and helpful feelings?
>  If
> Kronos and Hyperion were to fight, it would be?
>  Roman
> warrior?
>  Faulty time machine landed you in circa 200, now
> what?
>  The day you get what everyone gets before being out in the
> field?
>  Height gained by a rocket travelling at 48feet/s in 14
> mins and 40 seconds?
>  Einstein had it, so do we but not as
> pretty?
>  Saigō Takamori?
>  Boron?
>  Not so catchy moniker
> for one who sells baskets?
>  One who preys?
>  What is mostly
> eerie in novels, and more so if it's of young sheeps?

Someone make John rich!

Major Hint 1:

> Use boxofficemojo.com as reference. Release dates..

Major Hint 2:

> In case of ambiguity take the date which had a wide release...

Another Hint:

> The treasure has an exact location(coordinates).

Latest Hint:

> The treasure is on one of the islands of the Falklands Archipelago.

Final one:

> 5,2,5,3,5,8,21,5,9,1,12,14

Comment: Is 200 definitely correct for the time machine one? Just checking it's not missing a last digit

Comment: @Mohirl Yup. Correct.

Answer (score 17):

**Partial answer**

There's a common thread. All the answers are:

> movies.

(Final answer removed as OP indicated I'm on the wrong track)

<strike>I'm guessing the treasure is in</strike>

> Trinity Church, New York

because

> The individual answers don't seem to point at anything. But maybe they just point towards a movie, and the backstory is also a clue. I'm sure there's plenty of others, but the most popular movie I can find involving someone being told a bout a treasure by their grandfather is National Treasure, which I haven't seen, but Wikipedia tells me the treasure is found in Trinity Church.

Some of these are building on answers from **@prit.patel** and **@hagfy**, a better suggestion than mine from **@saltyeyes**, and one from an anonymous edit

When you are out prowling for friendly and helpful feelings?

> Good Will Hunting (1997) (credit @saltyeyes answer, deserves an upvote) looks more correct than my previous answer, The Pursuit of Happyness

If Kronos and Hyperion were to fight, it would be?

> Clash of the titans (1981/2010) (based on answer from prit.patel) or possibly Titanic (1997), see answer below from EightAndAHalfTails

Roman warrior

> Gladiator (2000)

**Faulty time machine landed you in circa 200, now what?**

> Roman Holiday??? (1953) (Back to the Future was a suggestion by anonymous edit)

The day you get what everyone gets before being out in the field?

> Training Day (2001)

Height gained by a rocket travelling at 48feet/s in 14 mins and 40 seconds?

> 42240 feet ... is 8 Mile (2002)

Einstein had it, so do we but not as pretty?

> A Beautiful Mind (2001) (thanks to hagfy)  (previously had Relativity?)

Saigō Takamori?

> The last Samurai (2003) (based on answer from prit.patel)

Boron?

> The Fifth Element (1997) (based on answer from prit.patel)

Not so catchy moniker for one who sells baskets?

> The Wicker Man (1973/2006) (thanks to hagfy)

One who preys

> Predator (1987) (thanks to prit.patel)

What is mostly eerie in novels, and more so if it's of young sheeps?

> The silence of the lambs (1991) (corrected thank to pbhj's comment)

Comment: But i wonder how these all will make up to find a treasure? I don't get that yet.

Comment: No, me neither!!

Comment: I think the backstory has the answer, in a similar manner to the clues. But no idea what that is.

Comment: @Mohirl For Einstein, maybe rot13(N Ornhgvshy Zvaq)?  And basket seller could be rot13(Gur Jvpxre Zna)?

Comment: Ah! I like both of those, I'll add them

Comment: Perhaps all those have a common location in them?  I'm not familiar with most of them.

Comment: just fyi... rot13(gur onpxfgbel sbyybjf gur grzcyngr bs gur svefg dhrfgvba V nfxrq ba guvf fvgr)...rot13(abguvat zber)

Comment: It looks like the movies may be relate to "The ...".

You have a couple of mistakes at least: "The Silence of the Lambs", "The Gladiator" .. although actually, the most recent one is "Gladiator" but there's a past "The Gladiator". Also the initial letters of the questions has "THE" in, like an acrostic. Might be irrelevant.

Comment: Added "The" to Silence of the Lambs, thanks for that. Left it off Gladiator  for now though

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with years movies were released in? Like a set of coordinates or cipher?

Comment: I don't think your time travel answer is right, (Mostly because in that one he doesn't go anywhere near 200) but I can't think of one that fits better...

Comment: Yeah, it was an anonymous edit but it doesn't really fit. I've replaced it with a crazy guess

Comment: Your "crazy guess" has got to be it; fits the clue much better AND it's another rot13(bfpne-jvaare)

Comment: Just a suggestion: Roman warrior might refer to rot13(Yrtvbaanver)(1998).

Comment: Also as idea with years-to-coordinates doesn't seem to work, got another one - looked up for number of rot13(bfpnef) won and got 205311400005 (if we go with Gladiator) and 200311400005 for my new suggestion. When split in half and used as coordinates, they point to either a middle of nowhere in Saudi Arabia or  to a point in the Red Sea near Island of Jabal Al lith.  Sry for double-post, ran out of time while attempting to edit previous.

Comment: @Oleksii rot13(V nz fher lbh'yy riraghnyyl svaq gur gernfher...)

Comment: Just realised there's a problem with the rot13(bfpnef) theory - rot13(Ggur Jvpxre Zna jnf arire abzvangrq)

Answer (score 6):

I came up with the same partial answers mentioned by Mohirl, except one:

When you are out prowling for friendly and helpful feelings?

> Good Will Hunting

As to the answer itself, a theory:

> Excluding the time travel one (which still stumps me), counting the letters/numbers in each title gives **OPI_KENNOLHT**. Seems like it could feasibly anagram to something?

Comment: I like your answer for that better - I might add it into mine if that's OK?

Comment: Go for it! :) all the others seem to fit perfectly except for the time machine one, but I can't come up with anything better.

Answer (score 5):

Of the Partial Answers I came up with, only one was not already caught by the other answerers. I think the answer to:

"If Kronos and Hyperion were to fight, it would be?"

is

> Titanic

and then

> all the answers are Academy-award-nominated films.

Comment: Ah! That works too, and probably better known.

Answer (score 4):

Partial Answer:

If Kronos and Hyperion were to fight, it would be?

> [Titanomachy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titanomachy)

Height gained by a rocket travelling at 48feet/s in 14 mins and 40 seconds?

> 42240 ft.

Einstein had it, so do we but not as pretty?

> Girl - Einstien pretty girl relativity.

Saigō Takamori?

> Samurai or Japanese ?

Boron?

> Symbol: B, Atomic number: 5

One who preys?

> Predator